# php process begin command line

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am running a PHP script via command line like so

```
php /Volumes/dev1/script.php
```

I want to use the `-B` (`--process-begin`) parameter so I can run a small piece of code before `script.php` does its thing.

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php, I should write something along the lines of:

```
php -B 'echo "starting ...";' /Volumes/dev1/script.php
```

But if I run it like that, it only `echo`s 'starting ...', but it does not execute the code in the file.

Comment: I can get it to work with `php -B 'echo "starting ...";' -f /Volumes/dev1/script.php`...  That being said, you have to hit enter after the `starting...` appears and it will launch the file, but won't terminate PHP after the script is done executing.

Comment: I keep getting `php -B 'echo "start";' -f /Volumes/dev1/cron.php` => 
`Either execute direct code, process stdin or use a file.`

Comment: I am doing it on Windows, and maybe I might have a different version of PHP.  I also just noticed, you should switch around the quotes (`"echo 'starting ...';"`) as it gave an error on my end with single quotes encapsulating it.

Comment: I'm using OS X Server, and I couldn't get it to work no matter what I tried. I came up with a workaround that does the job nicely and I think it doesn't have any downsides. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the message I kept getting when I tried using both `-B` and `-f` options I think one cannot execute direct code **and** execute a file.

The message was pretty explicit: `Either execute direct code, process stdin or use a file.`

But I found this workaround:

```
php -r 'echo "starting ..."; require_once "/Volumes/dev1/cron.php";'
```